# In view, add a sample no global "link" field foreach row

Tags: views, 8, entities

I created a view from the user interface. This view shows some content of a type of node.
For each node displayed, I want add a field "mylink custom" in this view for show a generated link.

I generate the link from a custom module, I want change the link according to the node displayed by the (row) view and some current user parameters.

How can I do that ?

I add a "Global : Custom text" default field in the user interface, but this field is global ! When I want get his value from a prerender hook view, I get only the global value for all nodes displayed in my view. But I want set a different value of my "custom link field" for each row of my view.

I didn't add a new field in my node structure because I want just display a generated text when the user go to the view page. I don't want save this value in each node because this text change each time an user go to the view page.

Thanks for help =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find how do with this usefull [guide](https://www.webomelette.com/creating-custom-views-field-drupal-8)

I created a custom field and I added it to my view. The content of my field is defined in the render method of the FieldPluginBase Class.

In addition, we can quicly and properly generate a FieldPluginBase Class and views.inc with drupal console (command 'drupal gpcf')